# Windows 7 uses up all of my ram after idling for 3 to 4 hours

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have been experiencing this problem for over a week now and it is starting to annoy me.

Here is what's going on:

I usually leave my computer running overnight (Really poor habit I have) It isn't anything great it is just a laptop that has 8 gigs (Only thing thats great about it) of Ram in it and it normally runs at about 1-2 gigs idling and then 3 maybe 4 when playing stuff such as Guild Wars 2.

However when I leave it sit overnight for maybe 3-5 hours and open it back up all of my ram is eaten up. No processes show anything NEAR that amount even when adding everything up. I have gotten RAMMap to check however the only process that uses the most is svchost.exe. It uses so much ram that when I first open the screen again and open something like chrome the screen flashes black (I am assuming its really trying to allocate ram at this point) I have no idea what it is? memory leak, malware?

Searched on google and didn't find anything that worked so far (Other than a restart) so I just needed to ask myself

Heck when I had Adobe after effects THAT didn't even use as much ram!

This is after I had it open and closed a couple things that "big" dip at the end is me closing 
svchost.exe

NOTE: those black boxes, I didn't draw those in that was actually there ... This is the raw screen cap

[image: Task Manager Screen Cap]

Here is my showing that svchost.exe is the only thing holding the most ram

[image: Resource Manager Screen Cap]

Just restarted my computer and this is my normal ram usage

Sorry this is only my second question on here so I do not have enough rep to post more than two links so you will have to copy and paste it

[image: Usage after reboot]

In Response to Daniel B and his request to have a screen cap of rammap

[image: Screen Capture of RAMMap]

Comment: Since you already know RAMMap, please do provide a screenshot of it, too. ;)

Comment: Hope this link helps you http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2889748

Comment: @DanielB Sorry it took me so long to get it up (I actually passed out for a couple of hours to get it to eat up all the ram) I think i should also say it doesn't eat up my RAM when I am using the computer it only starts when it has been idle for a long time

Comment: @AnveshVejandla I tried to run that update and it said not needed for my computer

Comment: Get [AutoRuns for Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) from [Sysnternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) for a comprehensive look at what is starting when you load Windows. A malware scan couldn't hurt. svhost is a generic process to run services from .DLLs. It is unknowingly assisting the bad process but it is not the root cause. 99.9% of computers are running things in the background that they do not want or have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your installed programs for anything you don't recognize? A friend had a similar problem, and it was being caused by some b.s. called "I.d.l.e. c.r.a.w.l.e.r.". Removal was a pain too, as it had created a huge amount of temp files that were not being cleaned up... so extreme that windows disk clean util. would just freeze while processing temp files. Uninstall would freeze during the deletion of temp files as well, creating a lot of headaches. You might have an unwanted software stealing what it considers to be unused resources, and not releasing them when you go to use your machine again. I would start here, and scan for ad-mal-spy-ware.
Good luck.

Comment: I "kind of" found the problem it had to do with Razer Synapse 2.0 ... It was because the new feature Stats and Heatmaps (When enabled) would start to slowly eat my RAM but would never show it as active memory. I believe (Just a hunch) that since this feature is still in beta that they have (had? I don't use it anymore) a horrible time cleaning up their memory after the program used it. Well, whatever the case I don't have an RAM issue now.